# Pandas return ValueError (Unknon string format)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert one of the excel column type from object to datetime after renaming the column name, but it keeps returning an

> ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Login Time')

Here is the code:

```
df_cols = ['Agent Name','Agent ID','Extension','LBLT','Login_Time','LOALT','LogOut_Time','Logout Reason','Logged-In Duration']
df = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx',names=df_cols,header=0)
df['Login_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Login_Time)
```

Hope some one can point out where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead for your last row:

```
df['Login_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Login_Time'])
```